# .NET 5 VB Late bound variables unavailable at run time due to Public member 'Visible' on type 'Application' not found

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, .net-5, late-binding

I've searched the forums for something similar to this, but most of the issues I've seen do not have access to the variables in the debugger and have issues with casting the object.

I'm running a C# application which calls a VB class called wrapper.cs, which uses MS Word objects. This code was tried and tested and worked fine with .NET 4.8 but now breaks in .NET 5.

I have a variable: `Protected m_wdApp As Object`

When the class is instantiated, it calls:

```
        Public Sub New()
        m_wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        m_wdApp.Visible = False
        m_outputFormat = DOC_FORMAT
    End Sub
```

This throws the following exception:
[image]

Now the above would be all very fine and well, if I wasn't able to actually look at the contents of the m_wrdApp and see that yes, they are all intact and are all visible in my watch Windows.

[image]
Using the Immediate window, attempting to access any of these attributes from the Word object throws an error (as you'd expect).

However, if I ask VS to "add a watch" to one of the attributes, for instance this "Visible" which we currently need, it comes out with this convoluted watch name:
[image]

I should note that all of this worked fine before upgrading to .NET 5, so I'm wondering if this is either a bug or there are some new rules for dealing with late bound variables.

Comment: Maybe cast it directly to `Word.Application` and don't use late binding? Why is late binding necessary here?

Comment: Why aren't you using Interop?

Comment: You can consider reporting your problem [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=61&entry=problem).

Comment: @dbasnett Actually, that was a good question and the answer is that we inherited this code from a legacy part of our app and hadn't considered updating it till now (.NET5 broke it). Now I'm after incorporating Word.Interop in the app and we have success. Thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

As @dbasnett and @charlieface mentioned above, we should be using Interop.

We added `Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop`

We also changed

```
Protected m_wdApp As Object
```

to...

```
Protected m_wdApp As Word.Application
```

And needed to update variables such as

```
Dim inlineShape As Object
```

to

```
Dim inlineShape As Word.InlineShape
```

and...

```
For Each hl As Object In m_wdApp.ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks
```

to:

`For Each hl As Word.Hyperlink In m_wdApp.ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks`

I couldn't see why moving away from late binding would impact us and I'm assuming the move the Interop is in line with .NET 5 coding guidelines, with their many improvements in Interop code in recent years.

Many thanks for this tip guys!